# Let $f$: $[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ bounded and Riemann-Stieltjes integrable for every monotone increasing function $\alpha$, is $f$ continous?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, riemann-integration, partitions-for-integration

My attempt:

Let $\epsilon$>0, as $f\in R_{\alpha}[a,b]$ there is a partition $P_{\epsilon}$ of $[a,b]$ such that $U(P_{\epsilon},f,\alpha)-L(P_{\epsilon},f,\alpha)<\epsilon$. To prove the continuity of $f$ in $c\in[a,b]$ I can take $\delta=||P_{\epsilon}||$, then for every $x$ with $|x-c|<\delta$ taking $P=P_{\epsilon}\cup\{x,c\}$, we have:

$$U(P,f,\alpha)-L(P,f,\alpha)<\epsilon$$

But $U(P,f,\alpha)-L(P,f,\alpha)=H+(M_{i}-m_{i})(\alpha(x)-\alpha(c))$, where H is the sum over the other intervals. And $|f(x)-f(c)|\leq M_{i}-m_{i}$, hence:

$$|f(x)-f(c)|(\alpha(x)-\alpha(c))<\epsilon$$

The conclusion is only possible if the function $\alpha$ is strictly increasing; otherwise, I cannot guarantee anything, so I think there might be some counterexample.

Commentary:

When we take $P=\{x_{0},x_{1},...,x_{n}\}$ a partition of the interval $[a,b]$ with $a=x_{0}<x_{1}<...<x_{n-1}<x_{n}=b$, we define:

$U(P,f,\alpha)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}M_{i}\Delta\alpha_{i}~~$  and  $~~L(P,f,\alpha)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}m_{i}\Delta\alpha_{i}$

with $\Delta\alpha_{i}=\alpha(x_{i})-\alpha(x_{i-1})$, $M_{i}=sup\{f(x): x\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}]\}$ and $m_{i}=inf\{f(x): x\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}]\}$.

$\alpha$ denotes any monotone increasing function: $\alpha:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I think you've not adequately set the context: what is $\alpha$? And what are $U$ and $L$ of three arguments? We can guess, but it'd be better if your audience does not have to guess. :)

Comment: Doesn't the function $f$ that is $0$ on $[a, (a+b)/2]$ and $1$ on $[(a+b)/2, b]$ give you a counterexample?

Comment: @RobArthan I'm not sure if that function is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable over any monotonically increasing function $\alpha$

Comment: Perhaps we can look further into this if you adress @paulgarrett's comment and tell us exactly what you mean by $\alpha$, $U$ and $L$.

Comment: @paulgarrett Sorry for the delay, I just added a comment explaining everything more clearly.

Comment: If $f$ is discontinuous at $c$ you can have a partition which includes $c$ and choose an integrator $\alpha$ with a jump discontinuity at $c$ and ensure that $(M_i-m_i) (\alpha(x_i) - \alpha(x_{i-1})) > K>0$ for some fixed constant $K$ and $c$ being one of the end points of sub-interval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$. Try to formalize this argument and write a proof. Let me know if you need more details and if necessary I may post an answer.